# How do I limit the posible options to be assign to a .net property

Tags: vb.net

Hello how can I have like a catalog for a property in .net VB .. I mean if i have

```
Property funcion(ByVal _funcion As Int16) As Int16 
    Get
        Return _funcion
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As Int16)
        _funcion = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I want to be able to assign to this property a limited number of options.

Example ..

```
Dim a as trick
a.funcion = (and get a list of possible attributes) ...
```

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having it be of type `Int16` have it be an `Enum`. It won't be perfect since someone could still get around it, but they'd have to make an effort.

Here's the documentation for `Enum`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h84wky1%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
Set(ByVal value As Int16)
    If value < 0
        Throw New ArgumentException("value must be greater than or equal to 0")
    _funcion = value
End Set
```

There is also [compile-time checking](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) for this in VS 2010 (though it requires VS 2010 Professional or greater).

Example usage:

```
''VB.Net 10 / Visual Studio 2010 Professional only
Set(ByVal value As Int16)
    Contract.Requires(value >= 0)
    _funcion = value
End Set
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it ended ...

```
Enum _funciont As Short
          Full = 1
          Table = 2
          Login = 3
End Enum

Property funcion() As _funciont  

            Get
                Return CType(_funcion, _funciont)
            End Get

            Set(ByVal value As _funciont)
                _funcion = value
            End Set
        End Property
```

Then when i put a s.funcion = ... get the list like a combo box .. !! thanks ...